# Transitions not working when setting .cssText on an element's style?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, css-transitions

I have the following CSS snippet:

```
.Test-Content {
  transition: height 2s;
}
```

and the following HTML code:

```
<div id="mydiv" class="Test-Content">foo</div>
```

Using pure JavaScript, I am trying to change the height of the `div` like that:

```
myId = document.getElementById("mydiv");
myId.style.cssText = "height: 0;";

/* ... Lots of code and situations where the browser re-renders the page ... */

myId.style.cssText = "height: 100px";
```

This indeed changes the `div`'s height from whatever it was to `0` and then to `100px`, but *without* any animation, i.e. immediately. I don't understand why this happens. After all, the `div` has `.Test-Content` in its class list, so *any* change of its height should trigger the transition.

Could anybody please explain why this is not the case?

When I change this to the following (very weird and worrying) code, it works as expected:

CSS:

```
.Test-Content-A {
  transition: height 2s;
  height: 0;
}
.Test-Content-B {
  transition: height 2s;
  height: 10px; /* or whatever number you prefer */
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="mydiv" class="Test-Content-A Test-Content-B">foo</div>
```

JavaScript: (Same as above)

It seems that I can trigger a transition by setting an element's `style.cssText` directly only if this element also has two classes with different `height` properties in its class list.

I have that problem in Firefox and Chrome (didn't test others so far), both at current patch level at the time of writing this.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple things you can be running into as illustrated by the following snippet.  The first time you click "Expand" or "Collapse", it won't animate, but then clicking "Expand" or "Collapse" after that will trigger an animation.

```js
document.getElementById("expand").addEventListener('click', () => {
  myId = document.getElementById("mydiv");
  myId.style.cssText = "height: 100px";
});

document.getElementById("collapse").addEventListener('click', () => {
  myId = document.getElementById("mydiv");
  myId.style.cssText = "height: 0;";
});

document.getElementById("unset").addEventListener('click', () => {
  myId = document.getElementById("mydiv");
  myId.style.cssText = "";
});

document.getElementById("setandexpand").addEventListener('click', () => {
  myId = document.getElementById("mydiv");
  myId.style.cssText = "height: 0;";
  setTimeout(() => { myId.style.cssText = "height: 100px"; });
});
```

```css
.Test-Content {
  transition: height 2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv" class="Test-Content">foo</div>

<button id="expand">Expand</button>
<button id="collapse">Collapse</button>
<button id="unset">Unset</button>


<button id="setandexpand">Set and expand</button>
```

Issues you may be experiencing:

#### 1. CSS can only transition from a value to a value.

Going from `cssText = ""` (the initial value) to `cssText = "height: 100px"` doesn't animate.  You can reproduce this by clicking "Unset" then clicking "Expand" or "Collapse".

#### 2. If CSS is set multiple times in a block of code, the browser will only process the last one.

The browser doesn't render changes immediately when they're set but instead switches between executing all executable JavaScript and updating the page based on what everything is set to.  You can get around this by breaking it into two discrete steps.  The best will probably be setting `style="height: 0"` in the HTML or adding a class with zero height.

Otherwise, you can do something like:

```js
myId.style.cssText = "height: 0";
setTimeout(() => { myId.style.cssText = "height: 100px"; });
```

This code sets the height to zero, lets the browser update the style, then executes the new code setting the height to 100px, which the browser can animate.  Of course, you only need to call `cssText = "height: 0"` because as soon as it's been rendered the browser will be able to animate.

You can see this in the snippet by clicking "Unset" followed by "Set and expand".  The element will immediately decrease to zero and then expand to 100px.  Clicking multiple times *shouldn't* appear to do anything because each time the browser will start animating down to zero then start animating back up to 100px within milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you very much and upvoted. This is a thing I regularly forget. However, in this case it is probably not the culprit because setting to 0 and setting to 100 happen in an event handler which handles a click on a button and are carried out alternating each time, so the browser has enough opportunities to render the page in between. I'll edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways to trigger CSS animations with JS is changing the class.

CSS:

```
.Test-Content {
  height: 0;
  transition: height 2s;
}
.Test-Content.taller {
  height: 10px;
}
```

And then, with Javascript:

1) For adding the class (animating forwards)

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").classList.add('taller');
```

2) For removing the class (animating backwards)

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").classList.remove('taller');
```

Comment: Thanks, and upvoted for taking the effort. But as I've written, the easy way is not feasible in this situation. Furthermore, I strongly would like to understand what actually is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This may not answer your question about *why* the transition isn't working with `style.cssText`.  However, if you're wanting the `div` to change height right when the page loads, I recommend using an animation instead like the following:

```
.Test-Content {
  transition: height 2s;
  height: 100px;
  animation: grow 2s;
}

@keyframes grow {
  from {
    height: 0
  }
  to {
    height: 100px;
  }
}
```

This eliminates the need to use JavaScript and better helps to keep JavaScript from doing what CSS can do.

Comment: Thanks, and upvoted for taking the effort. But I need to change the `div`'s height in JavaScript, because I should do it from within an event handler.

Comment: @Binarus Just out of curiosity: if you're wanting to do it from an event handler, why don't you have it in an event handler in your sample code?  Also, why are you using `style.cssText` rather than `style.height`?

Comment: ad 1) The code is quite large, and stripping it down accordingly would probably cost quite some time. ad 2) Because I have to merge the `height` property with other properties which might already be set in the element's direct (i.e. not-from-classes) style, and it has turned out that just appending it to the `.cssText` by far is the easiest method for this.